# PHP: Loop through all weeks in a date range (last 2 years)?

Tags: php, datetime, week-number

I like to iterate through all weeks in a date range that spawns 2 years. Starting at the current week number two years ago, until the current week number this year.

The problem is that a year can either have 52 weeks or 53 weeks, for example:

- 2015 had 53 weeks (the 53th was from 2015-12-28 till 2016-01-03)
- 2016 had 52 weeks (the 52th was from 2016-12-26 till 2017-01-01)

So this is currently my php code:

```
# start with the current week 2 years ago
$year = date("Y") - 2;
$week = (int) date("W");    // (int) removes leading zero for weeks < 10

$endYear = date("Y");
$endWeek = (int) date("W");

# iterate through all weeks until now
do {
    echo $week. " of ". $year;

    $week++;
    if ($week > 52) { // or greater 53 ?????????????
        $year ++;
        $week = 1;
    }
}
while ($year < $endYear || $week < $endWeek);
```

Comment: I would love to know why I was downvoted, so I can be a better member for this community.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to keep track of the bounds, let PHP do it for you.

```
$start    = new DateTime('-2 years');
$end      = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('W') . " of ". $date->format('Y') . "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/709326)

Comment: Your solution has a similar weired bug to Ross solution, it prints: "52 of 2015", "53 of 2016", "01 of 2016", ...

Comment: That's because according to the ISO standard there are 53 weeks in that year

Comment: It is important so set the week day to thursday, because according to ISO 8601, the week "belongs" to the year which still contains the thursday.

Comment: This answer is almost correct but not quite, since  not set the day to thursday. Please look at my answer, it is the only correct one so far.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of Ross Wilson and John Conde I found a solution:

```
$now = new DateTime;

$from = (new DateTime)->setISODate($now->format('Y') - 2, $now->format('W'));
$from->modify("thursday this week"); // see ISO 8601 

while($from < $now) {
    echo $from->format('W Y').'<br />';

    $from->modify("+1 week");
}
```

It is important so set the week day to thursday, because according to ISO 8601, the week "belongs" to the year which still contains the thursday.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using Thursday as the basis for ISO's week numbering. [Wikipedia has a in-depth explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) if one wants to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DateTime` and `setISODate` for something like this:

```
$now = new DateTime;

$from = (new DateTime)->setISODate($now->format('Y') - 2, $now->format('W'));

while($from < $now) {

    echo $from->format('W Y').'<br />';

    $from->modify("1 week");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your solution seems good, but it has a weired bug, because it prints: "01 2014",  "02 2015",... 
So because the the 53 week of 2014 is the 1 of 2015 it prints "01 2014"

Comment: Yes, because the first week of 2015 actually started in 2014.